# Can't Establish A Connection To SQL Server Using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to establish a connection to a local SQL server using this code:

```
dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Form;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Form", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = sda;
```

But when I press the button in my form it doesn't show me the data! What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error it just shows up the dataGridView empty!

Comment: have you checked there's data in the table?

Comment: @derloopkat Yes the database is ok and has data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need something like this

```
dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Form;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open()
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Form", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);   

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;//set it to datatable
        dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: This Worked! Thanks .

Comment: Please mark as is correct ans by click the tick at left

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the connection with `con.Open();`.

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Form;Integrated   Security=True";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Form", con);
        con.Open();
```

Also you had a lot of other problems like you don't dispose your resource which can lead to memory leak and not closing your connection, also you are not filling your adapter. Here is optimal way to doing it.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Form;Integrated Security=True";))
{          

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Form", con);
    using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com));
    {
        DataTable resultTbl = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(resultTbl);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = resultTbl;
        dataGridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```